# Importing buttons to a Gridview using Android, Xamarin and C#

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin.android

I am pretty new to programming and very new to Android Development with Xamarin.

This is a project that I am doing for fun and I have been hitting a brick wall for the past week and figured i would try asking here as nothing that I have found has been working for me.

I am attempting to populate a GridView with buttons from a list. The buttons already have their attributes set (title, width/height, and the button.Click delegate for what they do.)

How would I go about creating a GridView, and importing a list of buttons to it?

I thought it would look something like this:

```
GridView gridView = new GridView();
foreach(Button btn in buttonList)
{
    gridView.AddView(btn);
}
```

But my gridView is giving me an error "'GridView' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments".

Comment: You don't add buttons normally to a GridView.  You add the button to a Panel.  See my following posting.  In the posting I used a picturebox but you can use a button instead : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43822614/how-to-arrangement-of-points-on-the-chart-in-checker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GridView presents its data using the [adapter](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Widget.BaseAdapter/). I think that you need to read the very first tutorial regarding this: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/grid_view/

Comment: Thank you, i will look into it.